# How to send xml in a object of Json Response in a proper format

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am fetching a xml from database and sending it back to in json reposne using Spring boot but the format is not proper.The xml gets append with \n and spaces

Response Body(JSON):

```
{
   "environment":null,

   "policyNo":null,

   "latestXML":null,

   "interfaceMessageId":null,

   "product":null,

   "productCode":null,

   "shortName":null,

    "xml":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<TXLife xmlns:txr=\"http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2\">\n    <TXLifeRequest PrimaryObjectID=\"Holding_0001\">\n        <TransRefGUID>ID_323533B1-AE2A-A6EE-96FA-F1912312220D02E0F</TransRefGUID>\n        <TransType tc=\"103\">New Business Submission</TransType>\n        <TransSubType tc=\"1015700001\"/>\n        <TransExeDate>2018-03-26</TransExeDate>\n        <TransExeTime>06:34:07-05:00</TransExeTime>\n        <TransMode tc=\"2\">ORIGINAL</TransMode>\n        <TestIndicator tc=\"1\">True</TestIndicator>\n        <OLifE Version=\"2.22.0\">\n            <SourceInfo>\n                <SourceInfoName>E-App</SourceInfoName>\n                <FileControlID>ELIXIR</FileControlID>\n            </SourceInfo>\n            <FormInstance ProviderPartyID=\"VP00001\" id=\"FormInstance1\">\n                <FormName>IndividualLifeApplicationForm</FormName>\n                <QuestionNumber>substanceUsageTreatment</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>studentOrLicensedPilot</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>otherSportsActivities</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>driverLicenseOrMovingDUIViolations</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>felonyConviction</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>servingProbation</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>aidsArcHiv</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>diagnosticAdvice</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>treatmentAdvice</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>nursingCare</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>wheelChair</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>assistanceDailyLiving</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>sleepApnea</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>bloodRelatedProblems</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>cancerRelatedProblem</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>breathRelatedProblem</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>neurologicalProblem</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>mentalHealthProblem</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>digestiveSystemProblem</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>smokerHistory</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                    <SectionIdentifier>16</SectionIdentifier>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>alcoholUsage</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>otherInsApplications</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>highCholesterol</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>arthritisProblem</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>extendedTimeOffWork</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderMedicalDiagnosed</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderMedicalNotTreated</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderHyperactivity-ADD</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderFAS-Down</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderAnorexiaBulimiaSucide</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderAIDS-ARC</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderCancerHepatits</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderLungHeartDisorders</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderTestsNotStartedOrIncomplete</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>piMilitaryDutyOrReserves</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>lastOtherPhysicians</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>alcoholDrinksPerOccasion</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>alcoholDrinksPerWeek</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>ownTypeOfID</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>DriverLicense</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>ownOtherGovID</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>otherInsurance</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>childRiderAdditionalInfo</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>modifiedCoverage</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>modificationDate</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>modificationReason</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText/>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>pcVerifyIdentityPersonally</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>Y</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    <QuestionNumber>personalPhysicianExists</QuestionNumber>\n                    <ResponseText>N</ResponseText>\n                </FormResponse>\n                <FormResponse>\n                    \n                        <Coverage id=\"ID_1F5BF4D1-C46B-4675-8289-6CAC901F511E\">\n                            <PlanName>Foresters Your Term</PlanName>\n                            <ShortName>Foresters Your Term</ShortName>\n                            <MarketingName>Foresters Your Term</MarketingName>\n                            <ProductCode>T25X17</ProductCode>\n                            <LifeCovStatus tc=\"8\">PENDING</LifeCovStatus>\n                            <LifeCovTypeCode tc=\"6\">Level Term</LifeCovTypeCode>\n                            <IndicatorCode tc=\"1\">BASE</IndicatorCode>\n                            <CurrentAmt>200000.0</CurrentAmt>\n                            <InitCovAmt>200000.0</InitCovAmt>\n                            <CovOption id=\"COVOPTN001\">\n                                <PlanName>Accidental Death Rider</PlanName>\n                                 <RoutingNum>064000017</RoutingNum>\n                    <BankName>Bank1</BankName>\n                </Banking>\n            </Holding>\n        </OLifE>\n    </TXLifeRequest>\n</TXLife>"
}
```

Comment: Please show the code how you add the xml

Comment: what exactly you want to do? if you want to remove the \n new line characters then you can do that by using some of the regex parsers. This \n may be getting added because of the encoding specified with respect to operating system.

Comment: @Simon I fetch the xml from database.below is controller code @RequestMapping(value="/get/{id}/{interfacename}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getXMLFromTASIT(@PathVariable("id") String id,@PathVariable("interfacename") String interfacename) {
  InterfaceMessagelog xml=interfaceMessageLogServiceI.getXMLBasedonPolicyNo(id,interfacename);
  String DTOdtoObject=tbSitDomainToResponseMapper.mapDomainToDto(xml);

  return DTOdtoObject;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You should replace all whitespaces and \n \r \t before assigning the XML String.